# High memory usage with OpCache for PHP for Composer

Tags: php, laravel, composer-php, blackfire

While profiling with Blackfire,io,I get high memory usage from composer/autoload_static.php and bootstrap/autoload.php . 
 I’m using OpCache for PHP but still get around 4-6mb per total request. what is the normal benchmark?

Comment: How is 4 - 6 MB high?

Comment: How much do you get for a request that does nothing? i.e. just echoes a string

Comment: When echoing a string on localhost: Wall Time     913ms
I/O Wait      567ms
CPU Time      346ms
Memory       5.75MB
Network         n/a     n/a     n/a
SQL          3.26ms     5rq

Comment: So you can safely assume that about 4-6 mb is just the overhead of running PHP . Why is there SQL time in a simple echo request though?

Comment: you are right I ran through a controller , without the controller  and sql the Memory is  3.22MB

Comment: *normal* does not exist.

Comment: Lots of things happen for a web request and obviously your measurement depends on what you are measuring. I would say 3 mb for PHP overhead + 2 mb for framework overhead is actually on the lower end of what you'd expect. Maybe you'd some some improvement by changing webservers or perhaps changing PHP-FPM configuration (or switching to FPM if you aren't using it) or switching to a lighter framework. Also keep in mind that OpCache will actually use memory to keep the operations cached so switching it off will reduce memory as well but will make requests slower.

Comment: thanks, well I'm expecting to get thousands of http requests per minute to this route, so memory wise this will be pretty heavy. I'm using php-fpm but how will I improve the memory usage with it?

Comment: If you care about performance you should rather focus on how fast you can handle request, not how much memory it will take. Usually lack of CPUs is much bigger problem than lack of RAM.